# Received memory warning and app crashes

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

my app is crashing due to Received memory warning.

If i run the app for few minutes then on doing anything, the app crashes straightaway.

I have even checked for memory leaks but there are no memory leaks. Also the app is working fine in simulator.

What i have noticed is whenever i get a "Received memory warning", then "didReceiveMemoryWarning" method of every file in the project is called and then app crashes.

Any solution to this?

Comment: this question WAY too broad.

Comment: You must be doing something flashy, case is not same on simulator and device, devices have lesser memory than the simulators.. If you can provide your snippet of code, it would be easier to answer..

Comment: A general hint: use instruments to find out what is using the memory

Comment: THEN: release that memory (as soon as you can but at the latest at the message!)

Comment: @iphonic There is no specific place where the app is crashing.

Comment: @Daij-Djan I have checked memory leaks and there are no memory leaks. Also i have checked for memory allocations and live bytes are around 4-5mb on average and 12-13mb when app crashed.

Comment: As I know this is the problem with the handling memory . So Just check it with the leaks in the Instruments or paste the code at where it is crashing .

Comment: I would suggest take a break, and re-look your code, if all are ok, then something definitely in the code, may be a logic error, or an infinite loop..

Comment: temporarily comment out all code in `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. Maybe your app is not killed because it uses too much memory. Maybe your app kills itself because you do something wrong in `didReceiveMemoryWarning`.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch I am just using NSLog in didReceiveMemoryWarning method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to put it bluntly, you are just using too much memory. `didReceiveMemoryWarning` gets called so that you can try free up some memory yourself so you dont crash the app (free up things that aren't in use that can be reloaded later).

The simulator isn't accurate hardware wise when it comes to running apps, so i wouldnt always rely on it, and thats probably why you dont get the warning on the simulator.

I cant really say what is causing your app to use so much memory from the information you have given

Comment: I am releasing all the objects in the dealloc and viewdidunload.

Comment: yeah those wont help in this situation, because the view isnt unloading at this point, nor actually being dealloc'ed. this is for while the view is still alive, something is happening that is taking up too much memory, like loading a very large image or something. you will probably need to find a way to reduce your memory usage

Comment: I am initializing few arrays which are used again and again but when page reloads they are  first released and then initialized again.

Comment: are you sure they are not being held on to by some other object. going `someObject = nil` doesnt guarentee that it has been freed, since something else could be pointing to whatever `someObject` was pointing to, and therefor the reference count wouldnt have gone down to 0, and therefor not be deleted. can be tricky to spot and this situation wont show up as a memory leak either, because the memory in question is still valid because something is still pointing to it

Answer (score 1):

In ARC,the event(functionality) which create the received memory warning issue need to be inside `@autoreleasepool{}`.Received memory warning issue might happens which overload from device memory.

Answer (score 1):

Check app by instrument-->memory allocation

it will show all memory using by app and if there will any leak it will show.

Are you using heavy images?

Comment: I have checked my app by instruments. There is no memory leak. Also live bytes are around 4-5mb on average and 12-13mb when app crashed. No, I am not using heavy images.